# PHP multiple ob_start() and ob_end_clean() function not work

Tags: php, ob-start

I have this index page :

```
<?PHP
ob_start();
session_name('D12TYU');
@session_start();
ob_end_clean();
require ABSPATH .'/config.php';
require ABSPATH . '/class/backup.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
....... html+<?PHP ?> Code
</html>
```

in backup class i have this code for download backup file :

```
    class DB_Backup
    {
    //OTHER CODE

    public function download($file)
    {
    ob_start();
    $filename = $this->dir . $file;
    $fp = fopen($filename, "rb");
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($filename));
    header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename = " . $file . "");
    ob_end_clean();
    die(fpassthru($fp));
    fclose($fp);
    }

    //OTHER CODE
    }
```

now, when click in link(`?action=options&mod=backup&do=download&id=db-backup.zip`) for download file i see this:

[image]

i cant download my backup files. i think my problem is `ob_start();` and `ob_end_clean();`. how do can i fix my problem ?!

Comment: You have a `die(fpassthru())` in the middle of your `download()` method. `die()` terminates PHP execution entirely. No subsequent code will run.

Comment: why u use ob_* for headers? u simply put these headers to the output buffer and rewoke it after. then die() - fclose() would never been called this way

Comment: A more typical way of doing this is just to call `readfile($filename)` to read it from disk and to the output buffer. No monkeying with `ob_*()` needed.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: i change my code to this :`$filename = $this->dir . $file; header("Content-Type: application/zip"); header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". pathinfo($filename , PATHINFO_BASENAME)); header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename )); readfile($filename);` but after click i see same problem!!